# Как писать хороший код с меньшим количеством багов (TDD)

Tags: юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Читал статьи про TDD - тут все ясно с самим подходом. Пару раз пробовал, но как-то не идет и вот опять вернулся к этому вопросу.

Вопрос такой - вот к примеру решил я пользоваться TDD, но как вот мне придумывать тесты если я не знаю какие могут быть ошибки? Как я понимаю баг - это непредвиденное поведение программы и в плане такого подхода (TDD) не понимаю как его можно предвидеть. В моем случае я часто забываю что-то проверить/написать тест и часто вылазят баги, хотя я и сравнительно опытный разработчик. Бывает так - я напишу что-то, тестирую у себя локально и все ок, заливаю на sandbox сервер и тестировщик как-то не так кликнет (к примеру) и получает ошибку, а вот я как не тестировал до этого - не находил такого. В общем нету понимания как правильно продумать все тесты наперед и проверить чтобы не было ошибок в дальнейшем. Надеюсь понятно написал :)

Comment: если у Вас нет ошибок, значит либо qa плохой, либо компилятор сломался. Ошибки это нормально. Поэтому, пишите больше проектов, и, со временем, придет понимание.

Comment: Так как вопрос сейчас снесут, как не подходящий под тематику ресурса, посоветую вам книгу https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/136632098/

Comment: И посоветую не замыкаться на конкретной технике. Можете не использовать TDD, это не обязательно. Главное — пишите тесты как-минимум параллельно с кодом, так вам так будет легче, чем изменять уже написанный код

Comment: @KoVadim речь не о том, что нету ошибок. Речь о том как предвидеть макс. число ошибок наперед - придумать тесты под них  и после этого писать код уже

Comment: Даже ясновидящие предвидеть не могут (Иначе все бы были миллионерами). Поэтому, только опыт.

Answer (score 3):

*Не все приложение одинаково хорошо подходят для TDD.*

В целом, TDD говорит о том, что тест должен быть написан до написания кода. То есть сначала вы должны описать что приложение должно делать (ТЗ), потом писать скелет приложения с пустыми функциями, потом тесты на эти функции (которые поначалу все будут выдавать ошибки), а потом уже писать код функций.

Не пишите тесты ради тестирования готового функционала. Тесты должны рождаться раньше кода или из-за обнаруженых багов, или перед рефакторингом (для проверки сохранения поведения).

Пример: нужно написать приложение для расчета стоимости КАСКО. Пишете ТЗ, пишете архитектуру (что-то в духе MVP), пишете заглушки функций в модели считающих стоимость. Далее, пишете тесты подающие данные в них и проверку на правильность результата. Чем больше краевых случаев опишите, тем лучше. А потом пишите код (и дополняйте тесты, если в коде появляются какие-то хитрые ветвлеия).

Тестирование компонентов интерфейса и управления не столь просто и обычно не делается, т.к. овчинка выделки не стоит, проще протестировать руками. Модель же, при любом раскладе, должна все равно валидировать входные данные от управления (т.о. интерфейс заведомо не должен иметь возможности вызвать ошибочное поведение модели из-за своих багов)

Comment: В принципе это я понимаю - просто вот интересно как сами тесты продумывать. К примеру как продумать тесты джуну программисту если он не знает что вообще в принципе произойти может. К примеру в интернет магазине есть оплата картой  и он без понятия какие эксепшны могут возникнуть(бывает такое что не дочитал доки к примеру)

Спасибо за ответ - подчеркнул некоторые вещи для себя :)

Comment: TDD, да и вообще тесты (да и вообще все что угодно), не являются серебряной пулей. Всегда будут классы проблем, о которых никто не подумал и не предусмотрел. TDD это лишь одна из методологий помогающая взглянуть на решение проблем с другой стороны и, таким образом, заметить и предусмотреть решение части этих проблем. TDD помогает лучше структурировать код, поощряет "черные ящики" и ООП.

Comment: Сами тесты придумывать очень просто. В коде теста вы выражаете ваши предположения относительно того, что делает код. `const str = "{'key':'value'}"; const obj = JSON.parse(str); assertEquals(obj.key, 'value');` В данном случае вы ожидаете что метод `JSON.parse` превратит строку в объект. После того как написали тест, пишете реализацию метода и запускаете тест. Есть масса отличных книг на эту тему. Авторы к примеру Кент Бек или Роберт Мартин.